# Why do all one-star students look the same?

Tags: kill-la-kill

In Honnouji Academy, there are four levels of student: no-star, one-star, two-star, and three-star. However, only the one-star students all look the same. The only exception is for Suzuki, who stole a one-star uniform in the first episode.

[image: left: one-star students; right: Suzuki]

Is there any reason why that is?

Comment: It's probably just a way to show us that one-star students don't really matter, and we shouldn't focus on them at all. Two and three starred students are what we should be watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it's because they are unimportant to the plot and because the animators wanted to give a sense of a hive-mind mentality.

The ranks above are individualized as they are powerful and *worthy* of the viewer's (and Ryukko's) attention.

The zero-star students are individualized as well. Along with this, all the slums are very different looking to each other - In contrast, the houses that the richer student live in are very regular and similar to each other corresponding with their uniform class.

A good example of the higher rank's lack of individualism is

> When Mako and Ryukko start the fight club, They start to lose their individuality that they once had in the slums and become arrogant, greedy and unloving towards each other. Once they return to the slums, they regain their own personalities again.

Comment: I always thought that goku uniform made them looked like that since Suzuki body shape change after he wear it.